# Как ипользовать инвенторий в Ansible Tower или AWX

Tags: ansible

Был создан проект в Ansible (CLI), есть задача перевети все в графический фронтэнд Ansible Tower (AWX).

Все сервера статически указаный в *./inventory* сформированы на основе груп различные плейбуки и роли. Вопрос в следующем, есть ли способ использования уже готового проекта без небоходимости переписыать все под Ansible Tower (AWX)?

Пока вижу только полную ручную переписку всех хостов в БД Ansible Tower, что по времени весьма затратно.

Comment: А если создать "test-playbook" через gui, потом `find`ом пройтись по файловой системе и выяснить где это всё хранится? Ну и потом `git clone`, `rsync` уже готового.

Comment: @donRumata Нашел в доках уже встроенный функционал синхронизации БД с текстом хостов: awx-manage inventory_import --source=/ansible/inventory/ --inventory-id=1; думаю поставлю как ответ сам себе, первый )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопавшись в документации (в не столь подробной) нашел встроенный функционал синхронизации БД с текстовой версией списка хостов.

```
awx-manage inventory_import --source=/ansible/inventory/ --inventory-id=1
```

Так же есть возможность написать собсвенный скрипт (на любом скриптовом ЯП)

**Ссылки**

- http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2015/03/12/ansible-dynamic-static-inventory/
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tower-manage.html#inventory-import
- https://www.opcito.com/custom-inventory-management-using-ansible-awx-tower